# PHP require_once in HTML

Tags: php, html

Is it good practice to inject HTML code using `require_once ();` in the middle of HTML?

Example: 

`<div id="col_left">`
`<?php require_once ('../application/top_sidebar.php'); ?>` 
`</div>`

Comment: sometimes it is sometimes it not, with out context who can say?

Comment: @Dagon Under what situations would this be a way that's preferred over putting the HTML in one page?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it good practice to inject HTML code using require_once (); in the
>   middle of HTML?

Yes it is, after all that's why that function exists and including chunk of html that way is very common practice for example including header, sidebars, footer, etc to construct your templates.

That much php code is even permissible in MVC design pattern where you try to put minimum of php code inside the html.

Answer (score 1):

As this seems to be used in a page template, I think you can be sure not to call it more than once so you can use a simple `require` and save the `_once` check.